# Handling ± in a set of equations

Tags: plotting, animation, homework

First let  me post the question that I am doing:

[image]

You see for wave equation y2, there is a `±` sign. I know how to do `+` or `-` at one time. Of course, I can use copy, paste and do each case separately; yet, I don't think that would be smart. I am wondering is there a way to include the both `Animation` in two graphs? (Simple and efficient code)

The way I approach this problem is that first I define A1 as a constant, whose value is 1. Then I can vary the ratio of A2 versus A1. I would like apply `Animate` to variable `A2` and `δk`, because in the problem we are asked to `Animate` different amplitude ratio and phase difference.

Here is my code for the `+` case:

```
Remove["Global`*"]

k2 = k1 + δk;

y1[x_, t_] = A1 Sin[k1 (x - v t)];
y2[x_, t_, A2_, δk_] = A2 Sin[k2 (x + v t)];

yr[x_, t_, A2_, δk_] = y1[x, t] + y2[x, t, A2, δk];

k1 = 2 π;
A1 = 1;
v = 1;

xmax = 10;
tmax = 30;
range = {{0, xmax}, {-4, 9}};

pix1[t_] := Plot[y1[x, t] + 4, {x, 0, xmax}, PlotStyle -> Red]

pix2[t_, A2_, δk_] := Plot[y2[x, t, A2, δk] + 4, {x, 0, xmax}, PlotStyle -> Blue]

pixr[t_, A2_, δk_] := Plot[yr[x, t, A2, δk], {x, 0, xmax}, PlotStyle ->Black]

plot[t_, A2_, δk_] := 
  Show[{pix1[t], pix2[t, A2, δk], pixr[t, A2,δk]}, PlotRange -> range, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]

Animate[plot[t, A2, δk], {t, 0, tmax}, {A2, 1, 4, 1}, {δk, π/8, π, π/8}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
y2[x_, t_, A2_, δk_] = A2 Sin[k2 (x + # v t)] & /@ {1, -1};
```

Comment: Do you guys know how to change `\[Theta]` into math symbol when I ask questions on this website. I copy and paste my code from the MMA notebook, and those symbols just not change into the math form.

Comment: Press Esc and then type th and then Press Esc again. you can use Mathematica Palettes (in the main toolbar) to type all symbols you want

Comment: I know that. What I mean is that the math symbols in my notebook do not automatically change into math symbols when I copy, paste them to the website from the notebook.

Comment: @Lawerance Copy-paste as usual and then use [this plugin](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043/5)

Comment: @Lawerance and Algohi, you don't need `Map` since the constituent functions are Listable; you need merely: `A2 Sin[k2 (x + {1, -1} v t)]` or even `A2 Sin[k2 (x + {v, -v} t)]` -- *Mathematica* will take care of the rest.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Wow, that's awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Do you have an idea of how to assign different colors to `pixr[t_, A2_, δk_]` when I do the `Animate`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I mean some smart code (of course, you can always define a new function and copy paste, then change `Color`, then put the new function into `Show`).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I figured it out, still thank you!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you.